# A popover shown from the Spotlight menu is stuck on the screen

Tags: macos, spotlight

How do I get rid of it? It doesn't show up on task manager. It isn't dead, it responds to the  mouse wheel and scrolls up and down.

Screen shot below...

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Not really suited for this site, but try `Open Terminal`, `Type "killall SystemUIServer"`. Quite difficult to test as my Spotlight is working, but the Spotlight icon did disappear and reappear

Comment: Yes, please move to a.s.c - submitted here by mistake. /YR

Comment: @YiminRong. You can flag for moderator attention and ask them to do it. I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The process "QuickLook UI Helper" normally quits automatically after Spotlight is closed, but if it doesn't:

1. Open **Activity Monitor**
2. Find **QuickLook UI Helper**
3. Quit it (**x** button in the toolbar)

Answer (score 1):

Just kill spotlight., worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for me. The way I did it was: 1) Open Terminal  2) Type in: killall Spotlight

Answer (score 0):

Use Command + Space and the spotlight will go away

Comment: Nope, didn't work, it brought up another spotlight. It's probably hung, but still responding!